# how to make image tag image responsive without media queries and make the layout one screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know that is there any  way to resizes the img tag image without using media queries. I searched for it and tried all the answers but nothing worked for me. When I see the screen in windows system it shows the normal one screen display, when I see on normal screen laptop and macbook pro 13 inch it scrolls and when I reduce the window size to 75% in chrome it fits the one screen layout.
I tried to reduce the font-size for eg: font-size:2vw; Its working fine but i tried CSS:

```
max-width: 100%;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
    height: auto;
```

not working.
Is there any way or any script to make the layout in one screen and resize the image tag automatically. I don't want to use media queries

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the "width:100%"

e.g.

```
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/1200x400/000/fff" style="width:100%"/>
```

If you are looking for anything else. please edit the question and add the screenshots.

**UPDATED**

Try this:

```css
#images{
 max-width:50%;
 border:1px solid;
 float:left
}
#images .image{
 float:left;
 padding:10px;
 width:25%; 
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
 box-sizing:border-box;}
```

```html
<div id="images">
 <div class="image"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/80x100/000/fff" style="max-width:100%"/><br/>Test Text</div>
 <div class="image"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/80x100/000/fff" style="max-width:100%"/><br/>Test Text</div>
 <div class="image"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/80x100/000/fff" style="max-width:100%"/><br/>Test Text</div>
 <div class="image"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/80x100/000/fff" style="max-width:100%"/><br/>Test Text</div>
</div>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hi manoj actually its a company website and i cant share the code. If I am adding the width: 100%; then the icon image are getting bigger then the size

Comment: i am not asking for the code. If you can share a screenshot it would be good to understand. How many images in a row?

Comment: i have added one icon image in the image you can see the text size is small but the icon remains the same default size

Comment: there are four images in a row

Answer (score 0):

**Make image responsive without media queries:**

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" alt="">
```

**To make image responsive and no scrollbars:**

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" alt="">
```

**Make image responsive with constraints:**

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" alt="">
```

Comment: If I add the width the icon image size is getting bigger then the default size

Comment: In that case just add `max-width` and `max-height`.

Comment: the icon size is 96X69 so should i set it larger than this?? I have used css :
img{
max-width: 100%;
        width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
        height: auto;
        -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.1s ease-in; 
        -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.1s ease-in; 
        -o-transition:-o-transform 0.1s ease-in;
}

img:hover{
-moz-transform:scale(1.25); 
        -webkit-transform:scale(1.25);
        -o-transform:scale(1.25);
}

Answer (score 0):

Please add width:100% and height auto properties to img tag so that it will be responsive.
eg:

```
img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

Comment: If I am adding width 100% the icon image size getting bigger than default size